# First year spending of all customers

Tags: tableau-api

I want to get all customers' spending for first year. But all of them have different date of joining. I have transaction data which consist of columns [User ID], [Date joined], [Transaction Date], [Amount].

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Are you able to share a sample workbook? The exact answer will depend on the format of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An LOD calculation oughta do the trick.

```
{ FIXED [User ID] : 
  SUM(
    IIF(
      (
        [Transaction Date] >= [Date Joined] 
        AND [Transaction Date] < DATEADD('year', 1, [Date Joined])
      ),
      [Amount],
      0
    )
  )
}
```